# Removing the objects after doing clipping mask

Tags: adobe-illustrator, effects

I did the following effect

[image]

I did it using a circle with the required effect and a triangle with required effect, then I did object > clipping mask > make.

After I did the effect, I did create outline for the text. Now every time I do direct selection tool (A) and I hover all around the text, I can see the circle and triangle which I already did to do the effect.

My question
**How can I remove the triangle and circle and keep the text with the effect I did.**

**Is it ok to leave it like that ?**

Comment: Sounds like you're using Illustrator CS3 or earlier, CS4 fixed the 'clipping mask overspill' problem, see this thread http://forums.adobe.com/thread/317755 - as for how to clean it up and cut the clipping mask permanently, Flatten Transparency is the only way I know about.

Comment: well, Im using illustrator cs5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fine to leave it like that.

In some cases Pathfinder > Crop will remove the hidden objects without any negative effects. It depends upon what appearance options are applied to the internal objects. You could always try and then undo if it is not what you want.